# simple html dom on non valid markup

Tags: php, html, dom

I'm using Simple HTML Dom and it's working very well on most of my Data.  However, on is being a pain as the markup isn't valid. Is there any other way to do this in PHP.

I've got this result from a page I'm trying to extract the price from:

```
<taconite><replacecontent select="#basketcontents"><![CDATA[
                <table id="sellingb" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="15" width="600" border="0">
                  <thead>
                    <tr class="title">
                      <th width="47" scope="col" align="center">Book</th>
                      <th width="213" scope="col" align="left">Title</th>
                      <th width="139" scope="col" align="left">ISBN/Barcode</th>
                      <th width="63" scope="col" align="left">Value</th>
                      <th width="29" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                              <tr class="trrow">
                                <td class="tdbook" align="center" valign="middle" ><img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61JEp-wF3zL._SL75_.jpg" /><input name="offers_row_img[0]" type="hidden" value="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61JEp-wF3zL._SL75_.jpg" /></td>
                                <td class="tdtitle">The Last Of Us (PS3) [Video Games]<input name="offers_row_title[0]" type="hidden" value="The Last Of Us (PS3) [Video Games]" /></td>
                                <td class="tdisbn">0711719274551<input name="offers_row_isbn[0]" type="hidden" value="0711719274551" /></td>
                                <td class="tdval">Â£15.00<input name="offers_row_price[0]" type="hidden" value="15.00" /></td>
                                <td class="tdremove"><input type="button" onclick="removeitem(0);" value="Reject Offer" /></td>
                              </tr>

                  </tbody>
                  </table>]]></replacecontent><eval><![CDATA[jQuery('#isbn').val('');]]></eval><replacecontent select="#price"><![CDATA[Â£15.00<br /><input type="button" class="bask-sb" id="acceptoffer" onclick="confirm('By clicking OK you are accepting the offer of Â£15.00 for your 1 item(s).'); acceptoffer();"/>]]></replacecontent></taconite>
```

However, there seems to be a problem.  Simple HTML Dom only works on valid markup and this isn't valid.  What is dthe best way I can extract the £15.00 from this result.

Thanks.  It is much appreciated.

Comment: //td[@class='tdval']/text()[1]

Comment: PHP xpath doesn't recognize `text()`

Answer (score 0):

Only use valid markup, unless the markup is use by another resource.

One alternative could be to use `strpos()`/`substr()` for example:

```
$price = substr($input,strpos($h, "$")); // or euro symbol whatever you need
$price = substr($x, 0, strpos($x, "<"));
```

I assume your input is set to the variable $input.

This will only work well if you can be fairly sure that the next character after the price will be a `<` and that there will only be one price instance. If there will be more than one price instances you'll have to adjust it to get the right one(s).